# Entityframework +MVC + Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I dont want a view model.
I have a model as below

```
public class Person
    {
        #region private variables
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private string _middleName;
        private Gender _gender;
        #endregion
        #region public properties
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }
        public string MiddleName
        {
            get { return _middleName; }
            set { _middleName = value; }
        }
        public virtual Gender Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set { _gender = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
 public class Student:Person
    {
        #region private variables
        private int _id;
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
        private bool _isDeleted;
        private Guradians _guardian;
        #endregion
        #region public properties
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth; }
            set { _dateOfBirth = value; }
        }
        public bool IsDeleted
        {
            get { return _isDeleted; }
            set { _isDeleted = value; }
        }
        public virtual Guradians Guardian
        {
            get { return _guardian; }
            set { _guardian = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
public class Gender
    {
        #region private variable
        private int _id;
        private string _description;
        private bool _isDeleted;
        #endregion
        #region public properties
        public bool IsDeleted
        {
            get { return _isDeleted; }
            set { _isDeleted = value; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
public class Guradians:Person
    {
        #region private variable
        private int _id; 
        private Relationship _relationship;
        #endregion
        #region public properties
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
        public Relationship Relationship
        {
            get { return _relationship; }
            set { _relationship = value; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
public class Relationship
    {
        #region private variables
        private int _id;
        private string _description;
        #endregion
        #region public properties
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }


        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I am trying to create a view using Student Model, Scaffold template - Create.
Create template does not create html helpers for the complex properties.
I am new to MVC. Please help.

the view looks like

```
@model PracticeWebApp.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "create template does not create HTML helpers for the complex properties" (clearly a scaffolding issue)? Additionally, you can just declare properties without using private fields just like `public string FirstName { get; set; }`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto r u saying having private properties causing scaffolding issue ???

Comment: No, private fields are totally unrelated to this issue. From my view point, your scaffolding issue comes from relationships between model classes (including some class that extending base class, notice which property names are missing in view).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto if you notice, in the above code, Person class has gender property(which is another complex type). when I tried to genearate view using "Create" scaffolding and I am using **student model** (_**child class**_), the view doesnot have any helper for Gender whereas it has for other simple properties like firstname, lastname from the Person class(**_parent class_**).

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: use `public string FirstName { get; set; }` Instead ` public string FirstName {get { return _firstName; } set { _firstName = value;}}`

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh that did not help in any way.... "public string FirstName{get;set;}"

Comment: Please read this 
 
@TetsuyaYamamoto if you notice, in the above code, Person class has gender property(which is another complex type). when I tried to genearate view using "Create" scaffolding and I am using student model (child class), the view doesnot have any helper for Gender whereas it has for other simple properties like firstname, lastname from the Person class(parent class).

Comment: and @SoheilAlizadeh I am not facing problem in "firstname"
I have problem in "Why scaffolding does not generate Code (while creating the view) for "Gender" where as it does for "firstname".."lastname" etc ? What kind of clarity do you want ?

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem using same structure in VS 2013 with Create option and successfully created `FirstName`, `LastName`, `MiddleName`, `DateofBirth` and `IsDeleted`, but the `Gender` properties are not created. After **extending** `Gender` class into `Person` class, all `Gender` class properties are included into view.

Answer (score 0):

Use **primary key** and **foreign key**.İf you want to save database you can entity framework **code first** or **database first**.

Define controller post method

Answer (score 0):

I had took experiments about inheritance effect on scaffolding to create a view from model without data annotations (primary/foreign keys etc.), and found that your issue may be solved by inherit `Gender` base class into `Person` class:

```
public class Person : Gender
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The inheritance includes all `Gender` member properties into `Person` class using virtual property reference of `Gender` class, hence it will generate HTML helpers for `Description` property:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

NB: Since both `Gender` and `Student` class have `IsDeleted` property with exactly same data type (i.e. `bool`), `IsDeleted` used in view refers to `Student` class instead of `Gender`.